# Removing several desired rows from excel sheet using the second sheet

Tags: excel

How can I remove specific rows which has the same values in another excel sheet? of course there are many columns but I filter such that specific rows remained in the second sheet and we have those values in first sheet as well as other values. for example below I want to delete rows from second set with the same value in the first column of second set. rest does not matter

A   B   C

1   2   3

4   5   6

7   8   9

10  1   1

second set

A   B   C

1   5   6

3   3   9

7   7   6

Comment: What's the desired outcome here? To delete the 1st, 3rd and 4th row? Or only the rows where Ax matches Ay, i.e. delete 1st and 3rd row of your first set?

Comment: from the second set delete first and third row since in column one they are common

Comment: Oh, you said delete from the first set, not second hence my confusion. Have you considered conditional formatting to select the rows needing to be deleted or are you looking for a vba solution?

Comment: my bad. no.........

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This checks if the value in A2:A4 is in the other sheet in the A-column:
Formula used (I replaced the ´;´ with ´,´)

> ISNUMBER(XLOOKUP(A2,Sheet2!$A:$A,Sheet2!$A:$A,"NOPE"))

[image: conditional formatting]

The only thing left to do is  filter by color and delete the rows. Though do remember that deleting rows in larger quantities, if they're not continuous, can be quite slow.